# How do I manage permissions across multiple lambda aliases using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I'm using resource based permissions to manage access to lambdas, and I want to apply those permissions across several aliases per lambda.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "invoke_permission" {
  count               = length(var.invoked_by) 
  statement_id_prefix = "${var.function_name}InvokePermission"
  action              = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name       = var.function_name
  principal           = var.invoked_by[count.index].principal
  source_arn          = var.invoked_by[count.index].arn 
}
```

My lambda module contains aliases for dev, qa, and prod, and I don't expect to add new aliases frequently. I have three more entries, one for each alias:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "invoke_permission_dev" {
  count               = length(var.invoked_by) 
  statement_id_prefix = "${var.function_name}InvokePermission"
  action              = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name       = var.function_name
  principal           = var.invoked_by[count.index].principal
  source_arn          = var.invoked_by[count.index].arn 
  qualifier           = "dev"
}
```

This works, but it's wet (as opposed to DRY), and hard to manage if aliases are used in more detail. Is there a simple way to loop the permission statement over multiple qualifiers while also allowing multiple services to invoke the lambda?

Comment: What is `var.invoked_by`?

Comment: The type is `list(object({arn=string, principal=string}))` - just a holder for services that may need to invoke this lambda.